# Azure SQL Data-Sync. Issue with Syncing more than 30 Onpremesis Databases to single server

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server, azure-data-sync

I have run into an issue when trying to sync more than 30 on premises DBs on a single Azure SQL Database.

It is giving me the following error. Whats the best workaround for this error. We need to setup more than 30 SQL Databases (on-premises).

[image: This is the error message that I get.]

Also, how can we achieve a data warehouse for more that 30 stores keeping this error/restriction in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum number of endpoints in a single sync group is 30.

The Maximum number of on-premises endpoints in a single sync group is 5.

[image]

You have more than 30 on premises DBs, that's why you get the error when creating the sync group.

Azure gives the suggestion: create multipe syne groups.

Please see: [Limitations on service and database dimensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-sync-data#limitations-on-service-and-database-dimensions).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I found out a work around here but beware 30 end points limit is still there for per server per location. 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/sync-sql-data-in-large-scale-using-azure-sql-data-sync/?cdn=disable